# Microsoft Graph API Excel file synchronization issue file not updated after editing on cloud

Tags: excel, api, microsoft-graph-api, synchronization

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API to synchronize an excel file from the cloud to tables in an app, but when I edit the file on the cloud, even if it say it is saved, If I don't quit excel (web version), the file that I access with the API is not updated.

Do you know any API request that forces the saving or a workaround (other than a user action in the web app if possible) ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there no API for saving the excel sheet in MS graph, to update the excel sheet:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets/{id|name}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "position": 99,
  "name": "name-value",
  "visibility": "visibility-value"
}
```

For more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request

hope this helps.